# How to get all password values from all jsons and write it to a csv?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

This is my code below. I'm loading a list of jsons from path_to_oldjson and then writing that list to a csv. I'm now trying to do the same with the password values inside the json files. I'm able to write passwords into it. But its only writing the last password from the json to the csv, not the matching password to the relevant json.  How do I fix this?

Current code:

```
        path_to_oldjson = Path('C://Old Configs//')
        oldjsons = [file.name for file in path_to_oldjson.rglob("*.*")]
        path_to_newjson ='C://Encoded Configs//'

        #list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

        # this finds our json files
        json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_oldjson) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

        jsons_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Non Encoded Password'])


        def encode_password(obj):
            if 'password' in obj:

                listpasswords = obj['password']
                jsons_data.loc[index] = [listpasswords]
                print('Old password: ' + listpasswords)
                text = listpasswords
                sample_string_bytes = text.encode('ascii')
                base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(sample_string_bytes)
                finalpassword64password = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
                obj['password'] = finalpassword64password
                print('New Enyctped  updated: ' + finalpassword64password)

                df = pd.DataFrame({"HotelName": oldjsons, "Oldpasswords": text,"Newpassword": finalpassword64password})
                df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

            return obj

        for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
            with open(os.path.join(path_to_oldjson, js)) as json_file:
                json_text = commentjson.load(json_file, object_hook=encode_password)
                with open(os.path.join(path_to_newjson, js),'w') as f:
                    commentjson.dump(json_text,f,indent = 4) #updates the password  
                 
        print('finished')
```

Current csv output:

```
HotelName,Oldpasswords,Newpassword
hotel1.json,testpass1,newpass1
hotel2json,testpass1,newpass1
hotel3.json,testpass1,newpass1
hotel4json,testpass1,newpass1
```

Execpted csv output:

```
HotelName,Oldpasswords,Newpassword
hotel1.json,testpass1,newpass1
hotel2json,testpass2,newpass2
hotel3.json,testpass3,newpass3
hotel4json,testpass4,newpass4
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Just a side note: base64 encoding does not "hide" the password, i.e. one can obtain the original password, given the base64 encoded value.
You probably would prefer to use something like SHA256 where the likelihood of retrieving the original password is practically nil.
(This is assuming that you want to have the passwords stored secretly)

Comment: @JoseNuno Yeah I know. I'm just using this for testing purposes on my local machine. On the server, I'll change the encoding part to amazon secret key.